# Sometimes when I turn my PC on (Ubuntu 20.04), it says that my Bluetooth is off, but I can still turn it off

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

Sometimes when I turn my PC on (Ubuntu 20.04), it says that my Bluetooth is off, but I can still turn it off, as it's shown in the following screenshot.

[image: Bluetooth Off, but still able to turn off]

I can't connect anything through Bluetooth. How can I solve this?